# Cannot attach to auto-started LXC containers in (Fedora) SELinux

Tags: selinux, lxc, container

**Environment**: I am running Fedora 24 with LXC (2.0.6) containers inside and SELinux enabled.

**Problem**: Setting up Linux containers and starting them is all fine, and the same holds for attaching to a container via `lxc-attach` except for those containers that have been started by the autostart-feature of LXC (`lxc.start.auto = 1` in its config file).

For any auto-started container I cannot attach to, I can `lxc-stop` and `lxc-start` it again, whereupon I can directly `lxc-attach` to that container.

**What I've tried**: I already checked the proposed solution from this [bug-report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1405921), which consists of dnf-installing the container-selinux extensions, and adding the right label (`container_runtime_exec_t`) to the executables `/usr/bin/lxc-*` which includes `lxc-attach`. Though also proposed as possible solution, I have not added a label to the context of the base folder for my root-filesystems of all containers (`chcon -Rt container_var_lib_t /var/lib/lxc`).

**Output**: With manually started containers I have no problems to attach (`lxc-attach -n name_of_container`), but when I try to attach to a container which has been started automatically at system-boot, I get a message on the terminal like

```
lxc-attach: attach.c: lxc_attach_run_shell: 1325 Permission denied - failed to exec shell
```

while in the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file I get a message like

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1484836169.882:2969): avc:  denied  { entrypoint } for  pid=7867 comm="lxc-attach" path="/bin/dash" dev="sda3" ino=10289 scontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

If I look up the labels of the processes that run my containers (`ps -eZ | grep lxc`), I get

```
system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 2794 ? 00:00:00 lxc-autostart
```

for auto-started containers, as compared with

```
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 6399 ? 00:00:00 lxc-start
```

for manually started containers.

**My question**: I'm a bit too new to SELinux, but what I can see from the output above is that the context in which the container runs after it has been started on system-boot is quite different than the context my `lxc-attach` runs in (the former context starts with `scontext=system_u:...` while the my current context would is `tcontext=unconfined_u:...` from the audit.log above).

That is why I have to ask someone to explain to me: What kind of mismatch causes this permission-denied? And: Can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like at the time of this event that your `/bin/dash` was associate with either an invalid or no selinux context at all.

Here lxc-attach complains that it failed to execute a shell:

```
lxc-attach: attach.c: lxc_attach_run_shell: 1325 Permission denied - failed to exec shell
```

The SELinux avc denial seems to confirm the above:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1484836169.882:2969): avc:  denied  { entrypoint } for  pid=7867 comm="lxc-attach" path="/bin/dash" dev="sda3" ino=10289 scontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

A few this to note in the event above:

The target file (`path="/bin/dash"`) ended up with a special context (`tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0`) used by SELinux for failover scenarios. At the event either `/bin/dash` located at inode 10289 on device `sda3` was either associated with an invalid context, or no context at all.

Try to `restorecon -RvF` the context of `/bin/dash` at inode 10289 on device `sda3`. After you've done that see if the context is reset to something other than `unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0` with `ls -alZ`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```bsh
ausearch -c 'lxc-attach' --raw | audit2allow -M my-lxcattach

semodule -i my-lxcattach.pp
# or 
semodule -X 300 -i my-lxcattach.pp
```

Extracted from here: [https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1405921](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1405921#c8)